# How do X11, Unity, LightDM work together?

Tags: unity, xorg, lightdm

So I'm (probably too much) driven to understand how Linux, especially Ubuntu / Debian based distros work in the background, and for the graphical part, I'm a bit confused:

- x11 (or xOrg) is the core of all windowed / graphical stuff,
- Unity decides how to interprete x11's data
- LightDM displays it?

I'm pretty sure I have it all wrong, and Wikipedia is kinda enigmatic about those three, never talking about their relation with each other..

Also, to refresh the view after modifying shortcuts, must I restart Unity? im kinda clueless on what program does which part of the job

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, X11 essentially just draws on the screen whatever it's told to draw. Other things, like the window manager and compositor, decide what to draw, where to draw and when to draw it.

LightDM starts X11 on some TTY (usually tty7). Then it uses a "greeter" which tells X11 to draw a login page. When you login, it:

- optionally starts a new X11 process on another TTY (depending on whether someone is already logged in, and other config)
- and that X11 is told to start `gnome-session --session=ubuntu`, as specified by `/usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop` (or whichever session you picked to start, but assuming Unity for now...), which in turn runs `unity` after `gnome-session` sets up various things.

Unity, in turn, tells X11 to draw various things, like the panel, the launcher, where various windows are, what animations to do when you move the window or resize it, etc.

Have a look at [this set of articles](https://magcius.github.io/xplain/article/index.html) which might give you a better view at what X does.

Comment: Aaah I see, so I guess since LightDM started x11 and unity, restarting it will also kill the previous instances (seems like it)

Btw you the real MVP, thanks for the complete answer, appreciated :)